# rDEA Finding significance of betas in second-stage DEA

Tags: r, truncated

everyone.
I am building a two-stage DEA model following the article by Simar and Wilson (2007) using the rDEA package in R, but I am having difficulty finding where we can find the significance of the betas. Does anyone know how I can identify it?

I thought it was the beta_hat_hat_star and compare it with the values of a t-test, but it didn't make much sense.